# No Code Approved way to Pipe Water Heater Drain Pan?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, code-compliance

I'm confused about how to pipe the water heater drain pan. According to the 2018 IPC, which I fall under, PVC is not an approved material, but I can't find a drain pan with anything other than a 1" PVC connection. Is this something that inspectors just look over since everybody runs PVC or is there a solution that would comply with the code? I could jerry-rig an adapter from PVC to CPVC, PEX, or something, but that still leaves the PVC connection and seems a little goofy.

Here's the section of code I'm looking at:

> 504.7.1 Pan Size and Drain
> The pan shall be not less than 1-1/2 inches (38 mm) in depth and shall be of sufficient size and shape to receive
> all dripping or condensate from the tank or water heater. The pan
> shall be drained by an indirect waste pipe having a diameter of not
> less than 3/4 inch (19 mm). **Piping for safety pan drains shall be of those materials listed in Table 605.4**.

[Table 605.4](https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/IPC2021P1/chapter-6-water-supply-and-distribution/IPC2021P1-Ch06-Sec605.4) is "water distribution pipe" and does not list PVC as an approved material.

Answer (score 5):

I think the "code-correct" way is to buy drain pan with CPVC connector, such as [this one](https://www.holdrite.com/us/en/water-heater/pans/water-heater-cpvc-drain-pan).

[image]

Another option is to [replace the connector](https://www.supplyworks.com/Sku/313720234/camco-cpvc-1-in15-in-drain-pan-fitting-for-gas-or-electric-water-heaters-014717114424-11442) from PVC to CPVC.

The fact that you bought something that doesn't conforms to the code means you have to work around.

Comment: That makes sense. It's frustrating that the CPVC fitting is not in any big box stores in the area and appears to only be available in a very few places online. I'm assuming the majority of people aren't installing them to code.

Comment: PVC is rated to 140F, CPVC rated to 200F. However, water heaters keep water around 120-140F, so PVC should be OK. Code doesnt like PVC because it can melt and leach poison into water supply, but you are not using it for water supply...

Comment: I just don't want to have that dinged by the inspector.

Comment: in my locale you can email inspector with a specific question. that's how i learned i can't use air admittance valve

Comment: One might also argue that a fitting is not "piping."

Comment: @Huesmann as we say in russia "you will explain that to the judge"